# How to find highest values within groups?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a number of applications and a date.
I need to select the a year with the highest number of applications and a month.
My table looks something like:

```
 CisloSmlouvy | DatumZadosti
    121651566    | 3-1-2010 07:23:21
    121651516    | 7-5-2011 08:23:21
    121551567    | 1-9-2010 09:25:21
    121651562    | 3-5-2017 17:23:21
```

I want:

```
   Best year | NumberOfApplications
   2016      | 21565
   Best month| NumberOfApplications
   May       | 215
```

I've tried

```
;WITH resultset AS(
        SELECT
             COUNT(CisloSmlouvy)        AS PocetSmluv
            ,DATEPART(YYYY, CAST(DatumZadosti AS DATE)) AS [Year]
            ,RN = RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(YYYY, CAST(DatumZadosti AS DATE)) ORDER BY DATEPART(YYYY, CAST(DatumZadosti AS DATE)))
        FROM dbo.Smlouvy
        GROUP BY
             DATEPART(YYYY, CAST(DatumZadosti AS DATE))
            ,RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(YYYY, CAST(DatumZadosti AS DATE)) ORDER BY DATEPART(YYYY, CAST(DatumZadosti AS DATE)))
    )   
        SELECT * FROM resultset WHERE RN = 1
```

Any help would be aprreciated. Thanks.

Comment: sample data and the expected result please.

Comment: You want the highest # of applications in a year or a month? Your explanation is ambigous. An example would go a long way

Comment: I've cleared the idea in the edit.

Comment: I see your result, but which May is this? Can be any year, correct? Or does it have to be a month in the best year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window functions should help you:

```
SELECT TOP(1)
     YearCount  = COUNT(CisloSmlouvy) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(YEAR, CAST(DatumZadosti AS DATE)))
    ,MonthCount = COUNT(CisloSmlouvy) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(YEAR, CAST(DatumZadosti AS DATE)), DATEPART(MONTH, CAST(DatumZadosti AS DATE)))
    ,[Year]     = DATEPART(YEAR, CAST(DatumZadosti AS DATE)) 
    ,[Month]    = DATEPART(MONTH, CAST(DatumZadosti AS DATE)) 
FROM dbo.Smlouvy
ORDER BY YearCount DESC, MonthCount DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not easy, as there can be ties. I suggest to select best years and best months separately and use `UNION ALL`to combine the two results:

```
select *
from
(
  (
    select top(1) with ties
      year(DatumZadosti) as y, month(DatumZadosti) as m, count(*) as cnt
    from mytable
    group by year(DatumZadosti), month(DatumZadosti)
    order by count(*) desc
  )
  union all
  (
    select top(1) with ties
      year(DatumZadosti) as y, null as m, count(*) as cnt
    from mytable
    group by year(DatumZadosti)
    order by count(*) desc
  )
) unioned
order by y desc, m desc;
```